# QuerySet filter ArrayField contains exact match

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model that generally looks like this:

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    categories = ArrayField(..)
```

Let's say I have two categories, "`categoryA`" and "`categoryB`"

`categoryA`'s `categories` is equal to `[123, 562]`, and
`categoryB`'s `categories` is equal to `[5, 32]`

When I want to query for `CategoryModel`s which contain exactly `5` as an item in it's `categories` list, I use `CategoryModel.objects.filter(categories__icontain=5)`

Unfortunately, the above query returns both `categoryA` and `categoryB`, **not** just `categoryB`.
What is the proper way to perform this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `iexact`,

```
CategoryModel.objects.filter(categories__1__iexact=5)
```

Here `1` extactly matches to first element.

---

from [***docs***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[Index transforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#index-transforms)

```
>>> Post.objects.create(name='First post', tags=['thoughts', 'django'])
>>> Post.objects.create(name='Second post', tags=['thoughts'])

>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__0='thoughts')
<QuerySet [<Post: First post>, <Post: Second post>]>

>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__1__iexact='Django')
<QuerySet [<Post: First post>]>

>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__276='javascript')
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Still getting type errors: `categories"[2]::text) = UPPER(79) [...]`; "HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

I think it has to do with the int -> str?

Comment: @MichaelWard use 5 as string '5'.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer - I was unwittingly working with a wrapper that was transforming my data into an integer before invoking the function :) at first, I thought that it was Django doing some sort of unnecessary magic under the hood